# Does assigning to innerHTML delete HTML subtree?

Tags: javascript

I'm just discovering this amazing method of HTML DOM elements, [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

Is it good practice to first delete all the children nodes before assigning new content with `innerHTML`?  What happens to the old subtree when I make a new assignment?

```
var removeChildNodes = function(node) {
  while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
  }
};

var dynamicContentNode = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');

// Is this step important?
removeChildNodes(dynamicContentNode);

// (Recursively?) Populate the new subtree of HTML DOM elements
dynamicContentNode.innerHtml = '<div><p>Oh hai</p></div>';
```

Comment: To add to @Bjorn's answer: It's a terrible idea to remove the children first, because each such action triggers a redraw in the browser, making your UI sluggy. You lose all speed in that action, that setting `innerHTML` directly gains.

Comment: Now that you learned it, I recommend to use it only when needed (e.g. Ajax response). DOM manipulation as objects is preferred because deadling with HTML strings can be messy / error prone.

Moreover, if you are dealing with server-side code generation (e.g. JSP, PHP, ASP, ...), I recommend to generate the code on the server-side, avoiding JS DOM (client-side) creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` completely replaces the HTML elements for an element. They're just removed, and garbage collected by the browser. You do not need to remove the element's children first. The subtree is gone.

Comment: Can you reference your claim regarding garbage collection?

Comment: @Nit, you can see the garbage collection in action in Chrome's web inspector profiler for example.  Record heap allocations over time and then add and remove elements with `innerHTML`

Comment: @BjornTipling The fact that Chrome does it doesn't mean it's instantly done in all browsers.

Comment: @Nit, I certainly can't prove a negative for "all browsers". Perhaps you have positive evidence that there's a browser that doesn't garbage collect elements that have no purpose anymore? Like why would they do that? I'm pretty sure you're safe to assume that as long as you aren't holding references to the elements in memory with JavaScript, those elements are gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.  I assume `querySelector` returns a node by *reference* – otherwise, how could you use it to manipulate the node?

Therefore, I would expect the code below to alert "This is a test," then to throw an error because the variable `span` no longer points to a node.

IE alerts "This is a test," and then it alerts a null string.

*All other browsers* alert "This is a test" for both alerts.  It's as though no garbage collection took place.

**Update:**  In case garbage collection of a removed DOM node occurs when there were no references to the node, I put `querySelector` in a function.  In case garbage collection occurs during idle, I put the second alert inside `setTimeout`.  Within `setTimeout`, the variable `span` is still defined, but I'm surprised that the node it references still exists:

```js
function test() {
  var span= document.querySelector('span');
  alert(span.innerHTML);
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML= 'Bye, bye';
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(span.innerHTML);
  },100);
}

test();
```

```html
<div id="D">
  <span>This is a test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I imagine this is because each document operates in a single thread, and the execution of JavaScript prevents the document from actually updating while a script is running. This is why you can lockup the UI for a web page with a long running script. All clicks stop responding, scrolling is blocked, the whole page is locked down.

Comment: I also imagine that IE is updating its state within innerHTML, though not the actual page and that other browsers like Chrome schedule the alert with the old state and then give the chance the browser to update before the alert actually fires, but you'd have to look at browser code to see if that's actually the case. It wouldn't surprise me if it was though.

Comment: I had considered those possibilities, and I think I've addressed them in my update.  It's possible that calling `querySelector` on a node prevents garbage collection from ever happening on that node.

Comment: You could verify this in web inspector's profile tab.